# Displaying WebView in Outlook 2007

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I am using Addin Express 2010 , and want to develop a web pane view when the user clicks on a folder .

I am able to do this in Outlook 2003 .

[image]

The same installer does not display the same view for Outlook 2007. The one year technical support for Addin Express has expired, so I cant post it to their forum.

Then I looked into the Outlook Object Model and set the WebView to true, but still I could not see the webpane.

There is a similar question to this at [outlook 2010 add-in build custom WebViewPane without add-in Express](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9172764/102062). But in my case I have Addin Express 2010 and Outlookspy.

Any ideas on how to show the webview can be displayed in Outlook 2007 / Outlook 2010 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am answering my own question.

The reason can be found here - [You cannot add a URL to the Address box on the Home Page tab in Outlook 2007](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923933) .

I have changed the registry key, and here is a screenshot in Outlook 2007.

[image]