# Creating and overriding the default Outlook reader inspector

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm trying to create a customized view to replace the default Outlook message reader (*the reader is shown in this picture*).

[image: Standard Outlook Message Reader]

I can't seem to find any resources on this, is it even possible?

Comment: The picture you have is of Outlook **Explorer**, not an **Inspector**. The **Inspector** is a view of a single Outlook Item, whereas the **Explorer** is a view of multiple Outlook Items. See [MSDN for Outlook Object Model Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268893%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Ohhhh! That would explain why nothing I came up with was relevant..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for **Explorer Folder View** or **Web View Regions**. The only way to achieve what you're after is by [leveraging low-level Win32 APIs](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OlAdjacentWindows/) - outside the scope of what VSTO offers. See [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9173004/175679).

Here are two approaches:

1. Purchase [AddIn Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/index.php) which [already handles the Win32 integration](http://www.add-in-express.com/docs/outlook-folder-view.php) (*[see video here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hD4YJSYud9M)*).
2. Build the [**Adjacent Region** yourself using Win32 API calls](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OlAdjacentWindows/).

Comment: I might as well learn how to do it with Win32; should be a fun crash course into native C++, haha. Thank you