# Outlook Add-In Development - Show event in calendar

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in

I have a CSV File on my File-System with a list of events, and I need to read the events from this File and just show them up in the Outlook calendar along with other appointments, meetings etc, that are actually in outlook. 
So I don't won't to Save to the Server or Send any of these events read from file, just use the calender to show them.
Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, Outlook w3ill only show the appointments that exist in the given folder.

Answer (score 0):

As Dmitry noticed, the Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that (i.e. display items that don't exists in the folder).

But you may consider displaying your own form inside Outlook instead of the built-in one for displaying events and appointments from the CSV file and Outlook calendar.

There are sevaral ways to get the job done:

1. Use adjucent Outlook windows. See [Adjacent Windows In Outlook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2010/06/01/adjacent-windows-in-outlook.aspx) for more information.
2. Display a home page for the folder. The [WebViewURL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866188(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Folder class allows to set a string indicating the URL of the Web page that is assigned to a folder.
3. [ADX provides the WebViewPane layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172764/outlook-2010-add-in-build-custom-webviewpane-without-add-in-express) which is actually based on the web view technology. But in that case you will be able to use any.Net controls on the form.